# Send an email in c, server never reply after i send the body

Tags: c, sockets, telnet, winsock, winsock2

I have created a little program to send an email in c.
I did 3 functions :
Connect : to connect to a server by using socket,
SendAndRecieve : to send and recieve message to the mail server,
SendAnEmail : to write the text that will be send by SendAndRecieve.

Connect and SendAndRecieve are working perfectly.
My problem is in SendAnEmail. I don't know how to do finish the data step.

For each command, i recieve the answer of the server : 250 ******
But for the data one, it reply in first 354 but never 250 after the final full stop. I though it is the same protocol as telnet.
The final full stop = end of the body.
But it don't work. The mail server never reply.

Anyone know the solution to tell to the server that i finish to write the body ?

***Code***

```
SOCKET connexion(char* server_name,unsigned short port)
{
    char buf[1024]={0};
    int res_l= 0;
    int nbrecv;
    struct sockaddr_in   serverSockAddr;
    struct hostent     * serverHostEnt;
    SOCKET to_server_socket = 0;
    serverHostEnt = gethostbyname( server_name );
    if ( serverHostEnt == NULL )  {
        res_l = h_errno;
        return (SOCKET)-1;         }
    memcpy(&serverSockAddr.sin_addr,serverHostEnt->h_addr, serverHostEnt->h_length );
    serverSockAddr.sin_port = htons( port );/
    serverSockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;            


/* Create socket */                                        
    to_server_socket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );

/* connexion request*/
    if( connect( to_server_socket, ( struct sockaddr * ) &serverSockAddr,sizeof( serverSockAddr ) ) < 0 ) 
        return (SOCKET)-3;
    while( !buf[0] ) nbrecv = recv( to_server_socket, buf, 1024, 0 );
    printf("Welcome message : %s\n",buf);
    return to_server_socket;
}

void SendAndReceive(SOCKET to_server_socket, char * messagesend)
{
    char bufreceive[1024];                                                             
    int size,retVal,nbrecv;                                         
    size  = (int)strlen( messagesend );                                                

    // SEND THE MESSAGE
    retVal = send( to_server_socket, messagesend, size, 0 );
    printf("Envoye : %s\n",messagesend)   ;

    // WAIT THE ANSWER    
    memset(bufreceive,0,1024);                                                                                       
    while(!bufreceive[0])  
        nbrecv = recv( to_server_socket, bufreceive, 1024, 0 );
    printf("Recu : %s\n",bufreceive);                                                  
}             

void SendAnEmail(SOCKET sock)
{
    //ehlo
    SendAndReceive(sock, "EHLO localhost\r\n");
    //mail from
    SendAndReceive(sock, "MAIL FROM:<user@adresse.com\r\n");
    //rcpt to
    SendAndReceive(sock, "RCPT TO:<user@adress.com>\r\n");
    /data
    SendAndReceive(sock, "DATA\r\n");
    //Subject : Subject
    //
    //Body
    //.
    SendAndReceive(sock, "Subject : Subject\r\n\r\nBody\r\n.\r\n");
    //quit
    SendAndReceive(sock, "QUIT\r\n");
}
```

In your main, you must  set the port =25, use a real smtp server for server_name, and add a library that contain Winsock2.h

---

CMD :

```
Welcome message : 220 mwinf5d05 ME ESMTP server ready

S: EHLO localhost

R: 250-mwinf5d05 hello [10.162.66.36], pleased to meet you
250-HELP
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-SIZE 44000000
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 OK

S: MAIL FROM: <blablabla@orange.fr>

R: 250 2.1.0 <blablabla@orange.fr> sender ok

S: RCPT TO: <xapx35@gmail.com>

R: 250 2.1.5 <xapx35@gmail.com> recipient ok

S: DATA

R: 354 enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself

S: Subject: FlashRad

Ceci est un test.
.
```

---

I expected to be able to do like when i use telnet by myself :

Like it's explain in this [website](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404584/sending-or-viewing-emails-using-telnet).

So anyone know what how to say that i finish to write the body ?
Like the final full stop with telnet.

Comment: Maybe send one line at a time instead of bunching the subject and body together?

Comment: I forgot to add the SendAndRecieve fucntion :

Comment: Please *edit* your question to add information or code. There's a link below the tags.

Comment: I forgot to add the SendAndRecieve fucntion.
I tried it too. Sending the full stop alone. But the server never answer me. And i can continue to write thing

Exemple:
SendAndRecieve(sock, "subject subject\r\n\r\n");
SendAndRecieve(sock, "body\r\n");
SendAndRecieve(sock, ".\r\n");

Ofc i change a little the while do to that.
Thanks you for your answer.

Comment: it's HELO not EHLO

Comment: @ServeLaurijssen `EHLO` is an extension to SMTP. If it's not supported the client should fall back to `HELO` though.

Comment: Please continue to edit your question, first of all to show us a [mcve]. Secondly to show us the actual and expected output of the example program. Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: A link to explain the difference between ehlo and helo.
https://en.redinskala.com/what-is-the-difference-between-the-heloehlo-commands/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> RFC 821 says
>
> The third step in the procedure is the DATA command.
>
> ```
>         DATA <CRLF>
>
>      If accepted, the receiver-SMTP returns a 354 Intermediate reply
>      and considers all succeeding lines to be the message text.
>      When the end of text is received and stored the SMTP-receiver
>      sends a 250 OK reply.
>
>      Since the mail data is sent on the transmission channel the end
>      of the mail data must be indicated so that the command and
>      reply dialog can be resumed.  SMTP indicates the end of the
>      mail data by sending a line containing only a period.  A
>      transparency procedure is used to prevent this from interfering
>      with the user's text (see Section 4.5.2).
> ```

So you need to send a line with a only a single period after your body.

If you are waiting for a 250 after `DATA`, that would be a mistake too.  You get 354 first, and then the 250 after the period only line

[RFC 821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821)

Comment: I fail my explaination. I have that:

     Send : DATA /
     Recieved : 354 ------ /
     Send: Subject : Subject /
     Body /
          . // And now the server must reply 250 ---- but it doesn't.

Comment: Try sending "\r\n.\r\n" as your period only line, to make sure that if your body does not end with a "\r\n", the period is still on a line by itself

Comment: Excuse me, what do you mean by a "period only line" ?

Comment: From the RFC text above.  The data following the DATA command is terminated by a line with only a single period character in it.

Comment: It is probably a mistake to assume that a `recv()` is going to give you a whole response line at once in a TCP connection.  You should consider a TCP connection as a stream of characters rather than a series of packets

Comment: Thanks you to help me, now i can send emails. Is someone is asking the same question, the answer is 
SendAndRecieve(sock, "subject\n\rbody\r\n);
SendAndRecieve(sock,".\r\n");

And by modifiying a little the SendAndRecieve function to the while don't work for the 1st line but only for the 2nd (the one with the fullstop).